# npm login error Dockerizing angular project

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to dockerize an angular project that i have cloned from an azure repo
but the packages install in RUN npm ci is always exited with an npm login error.
i usually only need this project for an interface as i work on a backend service.

what i have tried is to clear cache and remove all the .npmrc files from the project.

```
FROM node:16 AS build
WORKDIR /app


COPY package*.json ./


RUN npm install -g npm@latest
RUN npm ci --legacy-peer-deps --no-optional


COPY . .


RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps
RUN npm run create-dynamic-bundles


RUN npm run build -- --prod


FROM nginx


COPY --from=build /app/dist/PodiumUI /usr/share/nginx/html
```